# Pipe multiple commands to single grep

Tags: grep, pipe

I'd like pipe the output of multiple commands to a single grep.

Example:

I'd like to combine these two lines:

```
smartctl -A /dev/sda | grep -e Reallocated_Event_Count -e Current_Pending_Sector
smartctl -A /dev/sdb | grep -e Reallocated_Event_Count -e Current_Pending_Sector
```

(Note that the only difference between these two lines is the disks are different: sda and sdb)

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try:

```
(smartctl -A /dev/sda ; smartctl -A /dev/sdb) | grep -e ....
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! Brackets were the key elements that I was missing in everything that I tried! I'll accept your answer when it lets me :)